# how many linear orderings on $\omega$ the are and how can we identify when 2 of them are in fact isomorphic.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, natural-numbers

how many linear orderings on $\omega$ the are and how can we identify when 2 of them are in fact isomorphic. I think that by instability argument there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ of them, but I do not know when exactly 2 of them are in fact isomorphic. So the first order logic language is $(\omega,<)$ or $(\omega,<,S,0)$. I do not know which one is a better language.

Comment: Just the well-orderings alone give at least $\aleph_1$ unique orderings.

Comment: Cantor proved there are at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ linear orderings on $\omega$ (probably early 1880s) and Bernstein proved there are at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ linear orderings on $\omega$ (1901)  -- see [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/111286/15780). Worth mentioning is that there are $\aleph_1$ many well orderings on $\omega,$ this being one of only a handful of relatively natural (and not highly technical) cases when a set is uncountable but not provably (in ZFC) of cardinality continuum. (Another in this last category are distinct Borel classes in the Borel set hierarchy.)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759979).

Comment: @AnneBauval when $(\omega,\le_1)$ and $(\omega,\le_2)$ are isomorphic, how can I check it ?

Comment: It is dangerous to talk about orderings of $\omega,$ because $\omega$ is an ordered set already. I assume you want countable linear orders?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You may be right. How do I check that 2 countable linear orders are isomorphic ? Just by exhibiting an isomorphism ?

Comment: There isn't a general way to check if two things are isomorphic. Rather, you need to construct $2^{\aleph_0}$ countable linear orders that you can show are not isomorphic, such as in my answer below. @user122424

Answer (score -1):

The standard trick is to encode a set of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ as provably non-isomorphic linear orders.

Here, we will use $\mathcal P(\mathbb N).$

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb N.$

Define:
$$P_{S}=\{(n,m)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb Z\mid m\geq 0\lor n\notin S\}$$
with the lexical order: $(n,m)\leq (n',m')$ if $n<n'$ or $n=n'$ and $m\leq m'.$

Define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $P_S$ as $x\sim y$ iff there are finitely many elements between $x$ and $y.$

We can determine $n$ from $x\in P_S$ by asking "How many equivalence classes have all elements less than $x?$" If $n$ is the answer, then $x=(n,m)$ for some $m,$ and this is entirely determined by the order.

An equivalence class corresponds to an element  $n\in S$ if it has a minimal element. So we can determine $S$ back just from the order.

So we have $2^{\aleph_0}$ countable linear orders distinct up to isomorphism.

It is interesting that they are all a sub-order of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb Z$ with the lexical order.